# addEventListener using for loop gives me an undefined result

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

Why does this piece of code give me a result of undefined? 
I have tested in the web browser. It shows me that li[i] is undefined. And I don't know why and how.
I know about closure. And maybe it should pop out the string 'dataToggle' every time I click each li element;   But someone could help me with more details about this specific question and what you think is important in understanding this question?
Thanks

```js
(function(){
  var innerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv')[0];
  //var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul.idiv li'); 
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 

  for(var i=0,len=li.length; i<len; i++){
       li[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             alert(li[i]);
             var data = li[i].dataset.info;
             showDiv.innerHTML = data;
       },false);
    
  } 
}());
```

```html
<div class="showDiv">Show data: </div>

<div class="outerDiv">
  <ul class="idiv">
     <li data-info="datashow"><a href="">111</a></li>
     <li data-info="dataHide"><a href="">222</a></li>
     <li data-info="dataToggle"><a href="">333</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, `i` is a variable defined outside your event handler function, which is incremented by each iteration. So when you finish the iterations of the `for` loop, the value of `i` is equal to`len`, which causes `li[i]` to be `undefined`. And if you ask me why it's value is not considered during the iteration, it's because your event handler function is only executed when the event occurs (not when you are setting the event handlers by `for` loop). So you can make a variable inside the function scope which won't be changed by iteration. Better use `this` from inside the event handler to get the same thing.

```
for(var i=0,len=li.length; i<len; i++){
   li[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert(this);
         var data = this.dataset.info;
         showDiv.innerHTML = data;
   },false);
}
```

## Understanding the for loop

Why the value of `i` is equal to `len` after `for` loop is finished? Let's have a simpler example to make you understand the situation.

```
var len = 2;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++; {
    //Do anything here
}
console.log("after for loop: i = " + i);
```

Lets's go through the iterations.

1. `i = 0`, matches the condition `i<len`, which proceeds with executing the code block and executes `i++` after that, which makes `i=1`;
2. `i = 1` now, matches the condition `i<len`, which proceeds with executing the code block and executes `i++` after that, which makes `i=2`;
3. `i = 2` now, fails to match the condition `i<len` and stops the iteration.

So, you have set the `i=2` before you go to step 3. So your final `console.log` after `for` loop will say, **`after for loop: i = 2`**

Comment: The value of i is len+1? I thought it should be the max num is  len,not len+1? Am i misiing something about the for loop?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct it should be equal to len, but li[len] is also undefined. Editing the answer.

Comment: sorry,I made a mistake in my above answer. the max num shold be length-1,that's len-1

Comment: Ok. If that is your guess, you are surely missing something about the for loop. the last statement in the for loop, `i++` is executed after each of the iteration in the for loop. So in the last iteration, when `i = len-1`, the codes are executed and `i++` is also executed after that. So `i=len` now. Then the loop tries to match the condition `i<len` and stops the iteration because of not matching the condition. But remember the value of `i` is already equal to `len` before that decision is made.

Comment: cool,i do have some misunderstanding about that. And do you have any idea for my code to work as desired?

Comment: I found your way did not work for letting it functioning.  And besides, i have an idea. what if i change the len to len-1 in my code ,it just did have effect on the second element. but i thought due to closure, it shoud do effect only to the last element rather than the second element

Comment: Well actually, I find another thing, `showDiv` is not defined  in the above code as far I can see, is it `innerDiv` which you were trying to set the `innerHTML` for?

Comment: If you make len = len -1, your condition will fail before you reach the last element. So it won't work as you are thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of scope. Inside the `EventListener`, you have an anonymous function, because of this, you are no longer in the scope of `li`. However, you can refer to it with the `this` keyword. See the alert that I've replaced in your code.

```js
(function(){
  var innerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv')[0];
  //var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul.idiv li'); 
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 

  for(var i=0,len=li.length; i<len; i++){
       li[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){ // you are now inside a different function block here.
             e.preventDefault();
             alert(this.innerHTML);
             var data = li[i].dataset.info;
             showDiv.innerHTML = data;
       },false);
    
  } 
}());
```

```html
<div class="showDiv">Show data: </div>

<div class="outerDiv">
  <ul class="idiv">
     <li data-info="datashow"><a href="">111</a></li>
     <li data-info="dataHide"><a href="">222</a></li>
     <li data-info="dataToggle"><a href="">333</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give more details caz i am a new learner of js,thanks ^_^ It seems that i add a handler on each of its li element, why the code shows the a element has a handler?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach in addition to the answers of other posters is to use a local scope with `function`. In JavaScript `function` is the most reliable way of creating a new scope. Taking the above example,

```
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var j = i;
        li[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = li[j].dataset.info;
        showDiv.innerHTML = data;
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

I have created a new scope that that will isolate the value of variable `i`. If you're using ES6 you can use `let` keyword to do just the same thing. All you have to do is replace `var` with `let`. You can also use `let` in a `for` loop that will give you a whole new scope that is local to `for` loop.

Comment: cool to make another scope. but why you make a j variable ,in which,i think, using i just work too.

Comment: @franklee. Yes you're correct. I added `j` variable just for clarity. There is no need to have an additional `j` variable. Since this is a new scope and its lifetime is only bound to its immediate enclosing scope, that variable will be garbage collected upon end of execution of its containing block. Another reason why I use that was, just to follow the same pattern we normally use for `var self = this` instead of directly referring to `this` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the particular `li` on which you want to attach the event

```
(function(){
      var innerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv')[0];
       var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 
          for(var i=0,len=li.length;i<len;i++){
           var thisLi = li[i];
           thisLi.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 alert(thisLi.innerHTML);
                 var data = thisLi.getAttribute('data-info');
                 innerDiv.innerHTML = data;
           },false);
      } 
    }());
```

When `click`  will be executed `i` will have value as 3 (in your case) so `li[i]`will be different. You can check the console of [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/0nadaLbb/2/) to check value of `i` on `click` event

Comment: is there any difference when i use var thisLi = li[i]  or just directly use li[i] in the above code? Thanks