# I am getting the error "cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined" in JavaScript. Please help! I am new to JS. Code is attached below. Thanks

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am getting this error on line 42 of my js(attaching code). Please help. I am a newbie at js

```js
let nums = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-items");
var i = 0,
  num = 0;
for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  console.log(nums[i]);
  nums[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    num = nums[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(num);
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="grid-items" id="number0">0</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number1">1</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number2">2</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number3">3</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number4">4</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number5">5</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number6">6</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number7">7</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number8">8</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number9">9</button>
```

Also, if someone has a better idea of printing the number from js on click, you can help with that. Thank you!!!!

Comment: All function share the same `i` which is `10` after your for-loop ends. Either use `let` and declare `i` in the for-loop `for (let i =0; ...` or use `for (const btn of document.getElementsByClassName("grid-items")) { btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(btn.textContent) }`. Index-based looping in most cases really is a thing from the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` loop to minimize your code and make it more cleaner.

See =>

```
let nums = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-items");
nums.forEach(element =>{
   element.onclick = (e)=>{
     console.log(parseInt(element.textContent))
   }})
```

> Note :  I used `parseInt()` method to parse integer from the string returned by `.innerText`

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard and should only be considered if you need its specific behaviour. Use `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```js
let nums=document.getElementsByClassName("grid-items");
var i=0,num=0;
for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    console.log(nums[i]);
    nums[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
        num=this.innerHTML;
        console.log(num);
    })    
}
```

Comment: @vaibhavn1 here in an element eventListener you have access to that element by this.
so you can get element innerHTML by this way, for more info about why you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217682/10925250)

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler uses variable `i` from global scope, and at the click-moment (when loop is completed) this variable points behind the array bounds, which causes an exception.

But if you make the variable `i` local to the loop-body, then each handler will have its own instance of `i` with a value specific to each iteration.

```js
let nums = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-items")
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  nums[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(nums[i].innerHTML)
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="grid-items" id="number0">0</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number1">1</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number2">2</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number3">3</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number4">4</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number5">5</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number6">6</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number7">7</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number8">8</button>
<button class="grid-items" id="number9">9</button>
```

Note the use of `let` instead of `var`, because `var` has a wider scope and won't be loop-local.